# Select Multiple Dates on CalenderCtrl in Python

Tags: python, calendar, wxpython

I have a wxpython GUI setup where a user sees two calendars.  They then select from the first calendar the "Start Date" of a schedule and then from the second calendar the "End Date".  However, I would like them to be able to select both from the same calendar -- is this possible?  For instance, highlight an entire week to where the first day highlighted is the start date and the last day highlighted is the end date.

Below is my code for how I currently use the calendars (works fine, would just like to reduce to one):

```
self.opt_startdate=cal.CalendarCtrl(panel,-1,wx.calendar._pydate2wxdate(opt_s),pos=(70,105))
self.opt_enddate=cal.CalendarCtrl(panel,-1,wx.calendar._pydate2wxdate(opt_e),pos=(300,105))

self.opt_startdate.Bind(cal.EVT_CALENDAR_SEL_CHANGED, self.opt_OnCalSelectedstart)
self.opt_enddate.Bind(cal.EVT_CALENDAR_SEL_CHANGED, self.opt_OnCalSelectedend)

def opt_OnCalSelectedstart(self,event): #Obtain Start Date on Calendar

    date=self.opt_startdate.GetDate()
    day=date.GetDay()
    month=date.GetMonth()+1
    year=date.GetYear()
    opt_s=datetime.datetime(year,month,day)

def opt_OnCalSelectedend(self,event): #Obtain End Date on Calendar

    date=self.opt_enddate.GetDate()
    day=date.GetDay()
    month=date.GetMonth()+1
    year=date.GetYear()
    opt_e=datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as selection - you can set the attributes (i.e. you could highlight them) for each data individually - so for a given range, you could set it to show background, looking like a selection.

however... how do you want to choose the end? it looks like wxCalendarCtrl generates those events on a left-click event. you'd need to manually catch the right-click event to mark the end (or just have so the first left-click selects start, second right-click selects end, next right-click selects start again)? and ideally as you mouse over the dates, it would highlight as if you were choosing that as the end before it's actually chosen. that could be a lot of work.

otoh, lots of real world implementations use single-pickers that are 'popup' - i.e. there will be a small button next to text showing the current value, and then pushing the button pops up a calendar control that lets you choose that date. i don't think having the two is that unusual....

Comment: I don't disagree that having the two is unusual -- I was more just exploring this to see if it is possible.  I think it would be cool to be able to left-click on the start date, hold the button down, and highlight to the end date -- then be able to automatically grab the start and end dates.  That's what I'm after

Comment: sure, anything is possible - but it looks like a lot of work. basically, you would need to catch the left-click and right-click mouse events, and then set the range yourself. (can't remember if there is a shift-click event, but you could capture keystrokes too) and then highlight the range yourself once selected. for bonus points, you could track the mouse movement and if shift is down, when it hits (or doesn't hit) a date, highlight as if that were the selection.